# Does PhantomJS fully implement Navigation Timing API and Performance Timing API?

Tags: performance, testing, phantomjs

We are currently doing our performance measurements by using Navigation Timing API and Performance Timing API for testing on IE10 (don't ask:-S), Chrome and PhantomJS. While the most important testing would be for IE10, it would be damn convenient if PhantomJS would at least not bitch about any reference to those APIs, since they are also at least present to some extent in unit tests (as opposed to performance tests), but it looks like they are not implemented in PhantomJS 2.1.1.
Does anybody know if our "looks like" assertion is an actual fact, or are we missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is supported, but not entirely functional - it returns null results for certain queries. See [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13093) for an extant issue report in the PhantomJS project.